# How to mock JPA repository's find method in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to UT my little project and I have a problem.
My application use a simple Layered Architecture and I can't happen to UT the service Layer.
In fact I'm trying to mock the class **[CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)** from Spring-data.
I'm trying to mock the method findAll of one of my repository that is extending this class but mockito can't mock Interface.
Is there a way to do it simply aside from creating the bean myself and filling it ?

[Update]
Here is the Repository Code :

```
package fr.kaf.interview.Repository;

import fr.kaf.interview.model.Book;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book,Long> {
}
```

Here Is The UT :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class BookServiceTest {


@Mock
private BookRepository bookRepository;

@InjectMocks
private BookService bookService;

@Test
public void should_get_All_books_from_database() {
    //Given

    Person author = new Person();
    author.setFirstName("Ka");
    author.setLastName("AwQl");

    Book firstBook = new Book();
    firstBook.setTitle("One Book");
    firstBook.setAuthors(singletonList(author));

    Book secondBook = new Book();
    secondBook.setTitle("Second Book");
    secondBook.setAuthors(singletonList(author));

    given(bookRepository.findAll()).willReturn(asList(firstBook, secondBook));

    //When
    List<Book> allBooks = bookService.getAllBooks();

    //Then
    assertThat(allBooks).containsExactly(firstBook, secondBook);

}

}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing more of your code? Such as your CrudRespository and your unit test test case?

Comment: @Brandon of course, please find attached the code

Comment: mockito should be able to mock that interface just fine - what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @Janar : Mockito cannot mock this class: interface fr.test.repo.Repository.BookRepository.
  The error is this one : "Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list."

Comment: Are you sure its the `given(bookRepository.findAll())` line that's throwing that exception? Find all is a non-final public method, so it should be fine.

Comment: @user31601 It fails before entering the test part.
I forgot to precise that I'm using MockitoExtensions given by JUNIT jupiter

Comment: I've noticed that my code isn't working when using Junit5 + Mockito from junit jupiter but it works perfectly fine with Junit 4 + basic Mockito.

I'm thinking that Junit 5 mockito isn't extending all the basic mockito behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the issue is that Mockito isn't sure how to inject the `bookService` into the Spring TestContext.

I would try annotating the test with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` as suggested at the bottom of the "[Writing Tests Dependency Injection](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection)" section of the JUnit5 User Guide.

The source code for that annotation is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringExtension.java).

I also think it's possible the `given` [BDD style of Mockito](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#bdd_mockito) and the `when\\then` style could have different results.

Answer (score -2):

If i remember well your test have to use this :

```java
    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```