# How to mock repository Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

My test class looks this way and I try to mock repository to return list of real objects.

In debug, I see that hashes of mock repository and service's repository during test are the same. Nonetheless I anyway receive empty `ArrayList`.

None of the previous answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674251/how-to-mock-jpa-repositorys-find-method-in-unit-tests) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053469/unit-tests-how-to-mock-repository-using-mockito) etc. helped me.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private BasicStuffRepository<Stuff> stuffRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void run() {
        // mock
        var mockObject1 = new Stuff();
        var mockObject2 = new Stuff();
        var mockObject3 = new Stuff();
        var mockObject4 = new Stuff();

        List<Stuff> mockStuff = Stream.of(mockObject1, mockObject2, mockObject3, mockObject4).collect(Collectors.toList());

        when(stuffRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(mockStuff);

        // run
        myService.run();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {

    private final BasicStuffRepository<Stuff> stuffRepository;

    public void run() {
        stuffRepository.findAll().stream() ....
    }
}
```

Comment: That the hashes are the same is good;  the question is are they the hashes of the mock or of an actual instance (although I agree it looks like it SHOULD be the mock) ?  In MyService.run, can you confirm which type it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you should use @MockBean not @Mock in test class.

MockBean is used to add mocks to a Spring ApplicationContext, not only "mock" an real object.